# Collatz algorithm generalization try-out (Collatz k-algorithm)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, hypothesis-testing, collatz-conjecture

(Text Updated 2015/09/16, please see edit comments for changes) Recently I have been reading about the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) here in Mathematics Stack Exchange, and also found the fantastic paper of professor [Lagarias](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Lagarias3-23.pdf) about it. Everything was so interesting (and I admit I did not know anything about the topic before) that I read all the questions about the conjecture in **MSE**, and the reasons stated by other users about why it is supposed that the algorithm is based on $3x+1$ and not other possible combinations.

Just to learn more about it, I tried to generalize the algorithm as follows, defining a Collatz 'k-algorithm', where $k \ge 2$ is the integer used to perform the division step in the iteration process:

> $$x_{n+1} = \begin{cases} x_n/k & \text{if $x_n \equiv 0\ (mod\ k)$} \\ 
>  \\ ((k+1)*x_n) + ((k-1)*(x_n\ mod\ k)) & \text{if $x_n \not\equiv 0\ (mod\ k) $} \end{cases}$$
>
> Being the stopping condition: $0 \lt x_n \lt k$

This approach to a generalization is able to provide a following number of the sequence:

$x_{n+1}\ \ /\ \ k\mid x_{n+1}$ when $k \not\mid x_n$.

> e.g., $k=2$ would be the classic Collatz conjecture algorithm:
>
> $$x_{n+1} = \begin{cases} x_n/2 & \text{if $x_n \equiv 0\ (mod\ 2)$} \\ 
>  \\ ((2+1)*x_n + ((2-1)*(x_n\ mod\ 2)) & \text{if $x_n \not\equiv 0\ (mod\ 2) $} \end{cases}$$

...because $((2+1)*x_n + ((2-1)*(x_n\ mod\ 2)) = 3x_n+1$ and the stopping condition is $0 \lt x_n \lt 2$, which is $x_n=1$.

I did a Python test for $k\ge3$ and these are the results:

> 1. The odd-k-algorithms are trivial, only those $x_0=k^i$ are able to reach the stopping condition (finite stopping time).
> 2. The even-k-algorithms are interesting, I have verified the pattern of the $x_0$'s whose stopping time is finite (no loops) and for a given $k$, those $x_0=k/2^i\in \Bbb N, i\ge0 $ are able to arrive to the stopping condition, and randomly some other $x_0 \gt k$ values are able to have finite stopping time as well.

It is just a guessing but while the classic Collatz algorithm ($k=2$) $3x+1$ (if the above proposed definition is valid to define the algorithm) would depend on a (mod 2) operation, generating two groups of $x_{n+1}$, one divisible by $2$ and the other non-divisible, due to the use of the (mod k) operation in the algorithm for $k \gt 2$, it would generate $k$ different groups of $x_{n+1}$ (one divisible by $k$ and the others non-divisible).

Regarding that point, what I have seen so far is that for instance for the 3-algorithm ($k=3$), if the next element $x_{n+1} \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and the previous last element whose congruence was $\not \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ was $\equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then a loop occurs later in the sequence, but on the contrary if the sequence is composed by elements whose (mod 3) value, not including those that are $\equiv 0 \pmod 3$, is ordered in decrease order the sequence arrive to the stopping condition.

> e.g.(3-Collatz):
>
> $24,8 \equiv \color{blue}2 \pmod 3,36,4 \equiv \color{blue}1 \pmod 3,18,6,2$ ($\color{blue}{End}$)
>
> $\color{red}{14} \equiv 2 \pmod 3,60,20 \equiv 2 \pmod 3,84,28 \equiv \color{red}1 \pmod 3,114,38 \equiv \color{red}2 \pmod 3,156,52 \equiv 1 \pmod 3,210,70 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 ,282,94 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 ,378,126,42,\color{red}{14} \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ ($\color{red}{Loop}$)

I would like to ask the following questions:

> 1. Would it make sense a generalization based on a modular arithmetic formula?
> 2. Is defining the stopping condition of a k-Collatz algorithm as $0 \lt x_n \lt k$ a correct approach, or should it be always $1$ as in the original algorithm?
> 3. What type of tests could I do over that algorithm to understand how it works much better?

Any hint about anyone of the points is very welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: I am very confused about what you think "bijection" and "surjection" mean.

Comment: I also think you're abusing "bijection" and "surjection". Would you clarify please?

Comment: @mercio probably more than bijection is injection what I should use. The algorithm for different $x_n$'s when $k\gt 2$ is able to arrive to a same $x_{n+1}$ due to the operation (n mod k). So more than one $x_n$ is able to arrive to the same $x_{n+1}$ (I thought the correct word was 'surjection' k:1), only the case when $k=2$ would be a 1:1 injection, so two different $x_n$ values would not reach the same $x_{n+1}$ value. Probably bijection is not the correct word (non English native speaker here). Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I have removed the bijection / surjection unclear explanation and tried to explain the same in more simple words.

Comment: The generalization has been done. The problems that come up are either trivial or else at least as hard as the original. Conway proved that there are examples that are undecidable. Look for his paper, "undecideable iterations".

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you, I will have a look to it, I would like to see the differences with the approach I wrote.